# Bootstrap label and input always in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm reducing browser width: the `<select>` input shifts onto a new line.

What I want: if the browser width is not enough space to keep the label and its input on one line, bootstrap should shift both the label and its input onto new line (i.e. keep them together).

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMZJPw

Comment: Which screens you are focusing for them together?

Comment: Written more clearly

Comment: you should copy your code right here (coz, I've slow internet connection) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your html structure something like this

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="form-inline col-sm-6" style="overflow-x: hidden">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">{{ 'commonLabelName' | translate }}:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="btn-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': newEventForm.name.$invalid && newEventForm.name.$dirty }">
              <input required ng-maxlength="100" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newEvent.name" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-inline col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">{{ 'commonLabelAction' | translate }}:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="btn-group" style="width: 70%" ng-class="{ 'has-error': newEventForm.action.$invalid && newEventForm.action.$dirty }">
              <select name="action" required class="form-control" style="width: 100%" ng-model="vm.newEvent.actionId" ng-options="action.id as action.name for action in vm.actionList"></select>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEMGay

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap classes like this

```
<div class="form-inline col-sm-6" >
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">{{ 'commonLabelAction' | translate }}:</label>
        <div class="btn-group" class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9" ng-class="{ 'has-error': newEventForm.action.$invalid && newEventForm.action.$dirty }">
            <select name="action" required class="form-control" style="width: 100%" ng-model="vm.newEvent.actionId" ng-options="action.id as action.name for action in vm.actionList"></select>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use inline css to make it easy to edit.
in your inline css, I find `width:70%` for `label` and `100%` for `select`.
Why not trying to set into `max-width`? to make them resize automatically.